# downloading image is slow even after using Async call in iphone

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, asihttprequest

I have to 20-25 download images of 50 Kb- 2 Mb each and show them in a tableview. 
I used ASIHTTPRequest asyn request to this. I observed that after some time the app gets stuck. This should not happen because I am using a async call. I thought something is wrong with ASIHTTPRequest and I observed that The didFinished selector gets called in the main thread. The only thing which I do is

```
-(void)didFinishedDownloadingImage:(ASIHTTPRequest*)request
{
    NSData *responseData = [request responseData];
    UIImage *image = [UIImage imageWithData:responseData];
    [[data objectAtIndex:request.tag] setImage:image];
    [self.tableView reloadData];
}
```

I don't think this should cause any problem. Also in cellforrowatindexpath I just do

```
- (UItableViewCell *)tableviewView:(UItableView *)tableview
                  cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    UserProfile * user = [data objecAtIndex:indexpath.row];

    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView
                              dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:@"ProfileCell"
                              forIndexPath:indexPath];
    if(cell == nil){
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewDefaultStyle];
    }

    NSString *fullname = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@\n%@",
                                    user.firstname, user.lastname];
    if(user.image != nil)
        [cell.imageView setImage:user.image];
    else{
        [cell.imageView setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"placeholder.jpg"]];
    }    
    [cell.label setText:fullname];
    return cell;
}
```

But the app is slow and freezes for 1-2 sec which is a considerable amount of time. 
I have seen apps which does this very smoothly. I tried using an image of fixed size 5Kb which has a very significance performance improvement with using the above code. I don't know why should that make a difference for big images in this case because all downloading is happening in other thread via ASIHTTP .

Comment: `[self.tableView reloadData]` is a very expensive operation. Selectively reload just the cell that you need to.

Comment: @Srikanth how do I convert image to thumbnail ??

Comment: @JackLawrence , I suspect setImage is taking time. Because I see the lag even when I scroll up or down. (reload cell is called when tableview is scrolled) It does not make any difference if I load it one at a time or the entire table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's easy to make assumptions about the root cause of a laggy/slow application. Instead of guessing, why don't you test your suspicions? Profile your application with the Time Profiler instrument. It'll tell you which methods and functions your application is spending the most time in.

Here are some ideas until you have a chance to profile:

You might consider downloading the full-res images and creating thumbnails in the background and then caching them in an `NSCache` object. You can also run `[UIImage imageWithData:responseData];` in a background thread. It's thread-safe until the point at which it interacts with the view hierarchy.

Selectively reloading a single cell *should* be faster than reloading the entire tableview, especially one with lots of images. Furthermore if you're doing all of the networking and processing on a background queue, there's no reason scrolling the tableview should be slow. Can you show us your entire implementation of the `-cellForRowAtIndexPath:` method? You've mentioned that you think `setImage:` is your slow point because rendering is slow. If you reload a single cell, only one cell needs to be rendered. If you reload the entire tableview, *every* cell must be re-rendered.

Comment: Good point. Makes complete sense to me. I will do as you suggested . I don't know how to use Time Profile instrument but I can find it out. I have also edited the post to let you know the complete cellForRowAtIndexPath . Let me know if you can point out some very obvious fault. Thank you .

Answer (score 2):

Please, replace your framework with [AFNetworking](https://github.com/AFNetworking/AFNetworking).

You can simple use..

```
IImageView *imageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0.0f, 0.0f, 100.0f, 100.0f)];
[imageView setImageWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://i.imgur.com/r4uwx.jpg"] placeholderImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"placeholder-avatar"]];
```

or... directly in TableViewCell

```
NSURL *url = [[NSURL alloc] initWithString:[movie objectForKey:@"artworkUrl100"]];
[cell.imageView setImageWithURL:url placeholderImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"placeholder"]];
```

"In the second line, we tell the image view where the thumbnail is located by passing an NSURL and we pass in a placeholder image, which is shown as long as our request has not returned a response"

Thats all!

Here you have an tutorial about that http://mobile.tutsplus.com/tutorials/iphone/ios-sdk_afnetworking/

Comment: This has nothing to do with framework. I want to download 20 images in one time and display all of them after I finished downloading them (paging kinda of stuff). I cannot do it using setImageWithURL because it is Async for all images. Moreover just for your reference I have replace it with AFNetworking operation request and it gave me same result. Eventually both of them uses NSOperation queue and it does not make a difference which library I am using. The lag is happening because of a huge image size (setImage) in main thread. Rendering for big image is taking time.